# What is the green tinge in my photo?

Tags: color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with fluorescent lighting and shutter speed?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/problem-with-fluorescent-lighting-and-shutter-speed)

I am shooting with a 5D MkII and a 50mm f/1.8 II. In the picture below you can see a really obvious green tinge on the top half of the photo, while another taken one second after, using the same composition and settings, is perfectly fine. The green tinge appeared in some of my other photos as well, sometimes horizontally while at other times vertically. My guess is that it could be reflection from all the green coloured chairs around and the green carpet, but if that's the case shouldn't it be consistent across all photos? I even have a quick burst shot where a green horizontal bar seemingly moved down the photo.
[image: photo with green tinge]

Comment: Is the back wall there also green, or is that _all_ from the tinge you are seeing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/problem-with-fluorescent-lighting-and-shutter-speed

Comment: @mattdm ALL from the tinge. @chills42 I think you're right, I'll close off the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably caused by fluorescent lighting, and the "bar" you see is due to a high shutter speed not being in sync with the lighting (60Hz IIRC).

Comment: US uses 60 Hz, Europe uses 50 Hz. Not sure what's used down under...