# Pink and green lines on shots

Tags: canon

I got a canon eos 6D 2 days ago for a low price, took a few shots yesterday and suddenly green and pink lines appeared all over the pictures as can be seen in the link.

I would like to know what causes that. If it is my lack of experience or I was sold a damaged camera and how I can get this fixed...

I got this effect, more or less pronounced and at different places in the image, for example sometimes only a large green line in the middle. I saw it in most shots at that shooting place, in these light conditions and camera settings. Trying again this morning changing aperture I could not see anything much, but suspect some pink effects near the picture borders.
I tried with two lenses, the pic here was taken with the 85 mm f1/8. Also tried the 50mm, same things. I want to investigate more but insights are more than welcome.

Thank you a lot !

[image: Pink and green lines over a door picture illuminated with white light]

Comment: *White light* isn't specific enough. What sort of white light? Fluorescent? LED? Or incandescent? Powered how? I suspect one of the first two. What was your shutter speed? Go outside and try it in daylight as well

Comment: Is that the entire image, or a crop?

Comment: In particular, see [Do fluorescent lighting and shutter speed create a problem with color cast?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/do-fluorescent-lighting-and-shutter-speed-create-a-problem-with-color-cast).

Comment: It is the entire image. The light well, it is the bathroom light, need to see what bulbs are in there. I had no time yet to see the details of the shots or try other environments so I will investigate more. Just asking in case someone has seen this before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal light and dark bands at variable positions within the frame is consistent with a **flickering light source**. Light and dark bands appear when the shutter speed is faster than the flickering of the light source. You can **try a slower shutter speed**, like 1/40s. If that fixes the problem, you can increase the shutter speed until just before the bands reappear.

The bands were likely absent in your morning pictures because additional lighting, such as from a nearby window, masked their presence, or the camera selected different exposure settings that did not show the bands.

Many people have problems with fluorescent lights, although incandescent and LED lights may also cause banding. Given the green and magenta color casts, I suspect you have fluorescent lights present. The widths of the bands are associated with the focal lengths of the lenses used.

See also:

- [Canon 5D Mark III - problems with fluorescent light](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25429/75526)
- [What causes these inconsistent dark bands in some of my photos from an indoor event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99456/75526)
- [Do fluorescent lighting and shutter speed create a problem with color cast?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4115/75526)

Answer (score 1):

The Canon 6D Mk II has flicker detection but alas the original 6D does not.  In addition to changing camera settings you can bring in some additional artificial light source to avoid the issue, for example a lamp or strobe.  Fluorescents are the worst but some LED lights will generate light/dark bands as well.  You can also use bounce-flash if you have a flash and reduce or eliminate the banding.