# What causes neon sign light to smudge like this?

Tags: lighting, shutter-speed, iphone, ac-flicker

[image]

In person, the sign is pure white.

This was taken with my iPhone X.

Is it the camera shutter speed?

Comment: Looks like a flickering issue, just as with many other artificial light sources.

Comment: What causes it?

Comment: The light is flickering and your camera does not take the picture all at once but scans sensor pixels line by line. Different lines are read during different flickering situation.

Comment: When you say "smudge" are you talking about the color bands the the left and center right, or are you talking about the secondary image of the entire neon assembly?

Answer (score 3):

> In person, the sign is pure white.

**The light and dark** yellow-tinted **bands looks like a flickering issue**, which is common with many artificial light sources. Some cameras have an anti-flickering setting. If such a setting is *not* available, you can try dropping the shutter speed to something like 1/40. If the problem goes away, you can gradually increase the shutter speed until just before banding reappears.

You can read about related lighting technologies on Wikipedia:

- [Gas-discharge lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp)
- [Neon lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lighting)
- [Fluorescent lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp)

> This was taken with my iPhone X.

The problem seems to be associated with **electronic rolling shutter** commonly used in phone cameras. Unfortunately, the solution would be to adjust the *readout time*, which is out of your control.

Here is another effect associated with electronic rolling shutters:

- YouTube: [Rolling shutter vs. global shutter: guitar string deformation](https://youtu.be/Dk6o5RAIaj4)

[image]

**Related Questions:**

- [What causes a band-like pattern in photos of a CFL?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24554/75526)
- [Pink and green lines on shots](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95794/75526)
- [Canon 5D Mark III - problems with fluorescent light](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25429/75526)
- [What causes these inconsistent dark bands in some of my photos from an indoor event?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99456/75526)
- [Do fluorescent lighting and shutter speed create a problem with color cast?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4115/75526)
- [horizontal bands on sony Ar7ii (some photos)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/108301/75526)
- [How can one correct intensity flicker due to AC line frequency?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59454/75526)

Comment: The bands you are describing are the **Vertical** yellow-tinted bands, Yes?

Comment: @Stan Yes.  If there are any other light and dark yellow-tinted bands, I missed them.

Answer (score 2):

Neon lights - *especially* true neon lights (as opposed to flourescent striplights, where a lot depends on the actual circuitry used. True neon lights usually run straight off several kilovolts AC from a transformer) - do have a dark/partially illuminated phase in every mains half cycle.

Any camera that does not capture all parts of the image at the exact same time will capture some of the image during the dark phase(s) if the shutter and/or readout speed is slow enough. If it is fast enough, you run a risk of an unexpectedly dark picture instead.