Why the red colour light on the bridge appears differently in these two photograph?
I took both photo in a nearby locations of the bridge around the same time and lighting condition (night time).
The first photo is from an iPhone 15. It is faithful to what I see with my naked eye. According to the photo info, here are the settings: ISO 800 24mm 0ev f.178 1/25s.

In the second one, you can see the light colour appears more like pink near top section of the bridge. Overall the red colour is more muted and lacks the vibrance. It was captured with a Fujifilm X-T5 and a TTArtisan 35/1.8 lens. The settings are ISO 8000, 53mm, -1.3ev, f4, 1/42s.

I want to understand the cause of the difference and is there any way I can make X-T5 to show the same vibrant red colour.

Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87207/9161

The second is rather less exposed than the first as we can see from the building lights.  I think with some Lightroom adjustment you can get pretty close.  Start by boosting the exposure and particularly the red channel.

Is the one from the X-T5 the camera JPG?  There are quite a lot of settings to influence the look of the generated JPGs.  Most importantly the film simulations, which affect the colors quite a lot.

IMO, the primary difference is that the iphone is implementing some version of HDR compositing of multiple exposures. It has at least two exposures combined; a lighter exposure for the sky and dark regions, and a darker exposure for the lights/highlights. Many phone cameras do this (and more) automatically without necessarily telling you; the reported exposure settings are obviously not accurate/true (maybe the average?).
The X-T5 image has metered and exposed for a single "average" exposure. This results in the dark regions being less exposed (you can't see the sky or details in the buildings), and the lighter regions to be recorded brighter. The lighter regions being brighter causes the colors to wash out and record less saturated... e.g. it is usually best to "underexpose" a sunset to get the best colors.
I don't own an iphone, so I don't know if you can disable the exposure compositing/HDR. But HDR does a better job of simulating what a scene looks like to you because your eyes also adjust to the variable brightnesses within a scene as you scan and focus on those regions.
The X-T5 does have an HDR mode, and it also has some dynamic range optimization/expansion settings you could use; but I have no experience with them. I've only ever used manual exposure blending/compositing; and that is what I would recommend for best results (but least convenience/ease).

Yes you very likely can get similar photo with Fuji. There is a ton of image settings which are described in the manual. Relevant settings are: D RANGE PRIORITY, COLOR (density), CLARITY (similar to HDR but does not require multiple photps, Advanced Filter Options (High Key).

I do not know how iPhones camera works and I do not understand what "f.178" means. On the surface the most important difference is that Fujifilm's image is significantly darker (or "underexposed" if you prefer) compared to iPhone's image. If it was not there would be much less difference.
Another important difference is colour saturation. It seems that Fuji has less saturation by default.
The bridge has clipping red channel on the iPhone photo. While i agree that iPhone's photo overall looks more realistic I bet I could discern the bridge details which Fuji preserved.
Fuji also has some settings regarding highlights or HDR, they can allow to have well exposed photo but preserve the colours of the bridge better.
I am also amused by the black water lacking bridge reflections on Fuji's photo. I have no clue why it happened but I might tell better if you photograph same bridge with similar wind blowing (creating similar waves) to a raw file.

The iPhone almost certainly combined multiple images shot at different exposures.

@MichaelC that does not tell anything if you do not specify the algorithm used.

Sure it does. It uses the dimmer exposure to prevent washing out the highlights and the brighter exposure to show detail in the shadows. That's the entire point of using multiple frames with different exposures. Saturation can be more intense in the middle of the brightness range than at either end, where highlights blow out into white and shadows descend into black.

@MichaelC "It uses ... to prevent washing out ..." - it does not even begin to describe what exactly is done.
